# 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for code copied from tutorial for tensorflow eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the program from https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager, and I'm running into a syntax error. Code below.

```
## Note: Rerunning this cell uses the same model variables
# keep results for plotting
train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []
num_epochs = 201
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  epoch_loss_avg = tfe.metrics.Mean()
  epoch_accuracy = tfe.metrics.Accuracy()  
# Training loop - using batches of 32
  for x, y in train_dataset:
  # Optimize the model
    grads = grad(model, x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,model.variables),global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
    # Track progress
    epoch_loss_avg(loss(model, x, y))  # add current batch loss
    # compare predicted label to actual label
    epoch_accuracy(tf.argmax(model(x), axis=1, output_type=tf.int32), y)
  # end epoch
  train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
  train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())
```

This is the error.

```
train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
File "<stdin>", line 14
train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

@

Comment: There are Indentations problems in your code. can you please fix those first. like in line `for x, y in train_dataset:`  Also what is train_dataset please read docs before compiling your code.

Comment: indentation problems have been fixed, they weren't on my code but I was unfamiliar with stack overflow formatting. train_dataset_url = "download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"; train_dataset_fp = tf.keras.utils.get_file(fname=os.path.basename(train_dataset_url), origin=train_dataset_url) print("Local copy of the dataset file: {}".format(train_dataset_fp))